# How can I make third party class objects available from a Class Library?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class

I am trying to make a Class Library to wrap a third party product, using ASP.NET VB.

A sample page has the following:

```
Imports Gurock.SmartInspect

SiAuto.Si.Enabled = True
SiAuto.Main.Color = Color.Green
SiAuto.Main.LogMessage("START LOGGING")
SiAuto.Main.Color = toggleCurrentMethodColour()
```

SiAuto is defined in the Object Browser as

```
Public NotInheritable Class SiAuto
    Inherits System.Object
    ' Member of Gurock.SmartInspect
```

In a project that will use the class library, I want to reference SiAuto too:

```
    Imports SouthViewSolutions.SmartInspect
```

(My Class Library)

```
    Log.EnterMethod(My.Application, method & ".Process")
```

(this is from My Class Library. This bit works)

```
    If (SiAuto.Si.Level ...
```

The last statement wants to use the SiAuto Object. How do I make this available to my project?

Comment: Why don't add a reference of the class lib dll to your project reference?

Comment: The whole purpose of my Class Library is not to have to include the Third Party dlls in my Project references.

Comment: In that case, expose a property/method in your class library through which you can access the object in third party dll.

Comment: I don't know what 'expose a property/method' means.

Comment: 'expose a property/method in your class library' - How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> to wrap a third party product [so I don't] have to include the Third Party dlls in my Project references

Then you can't access any part of the third-party library from your calling code. As soon as you use something from the `SiAuto` namespace, *your* code needs to know about the assembly containing that namespace.

You can probably wrap those members you want to access in your library like this (C#):

```
Namespace YourLibrary
    Public NotInheritable Class WrapperClass
        Public Shared Property Level() As Integer
            Get
                Return SiAuto.Si.Level
            End Get
            Set
                SiAuto.Si.Level = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then you can access that from the calling code:

```
If (YourLibrary.WrapperClass.Level ...
```

Note that if `Level` is of a type defined in the `SiAuto` namespace (as opposed to the `int` demonstrated here), you'll have to write wrapping and conversion code for that too.

See for example [Common Infrastructure's Common.Logging project](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging), which aims to decouple code from specific logging implementations. You can swap the actual logging implementation without changing any of the calling code, but in order to enable this, they wrote a layer that wraps every logging aspect they deemed common.

Comment: Now you have lost me - I am looking for a VB answer.

Comment: @Steve I have edited the code. I am assuming `SiAuto.Si.Level` is static or shared in VB.

Comment: OK. I have found another way round this, and take all references to SiAuto out of my main Project, and moved all the code that did refer to it into my Class Library. That makes sense.